# How to navigate android activity to xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

Unable to navigate activity to xamarin forms, I want to return the result from activity to xamarin forms.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity you have to override method:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
```

and then you can do whatever you want to pass it to Forms logic.